# jquery TypeError: a is null in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm implementing jquery smooth scroll to anchor in wordpress. Everything seems to work on the front page without errors, however, when I'm on the any other page, I get the jquery TypeError: a is null error in main.js.

This is my link structure with sections on the front page:

```
<li id="menu-item-631" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-631"><a class="anchor_scroll" href="#services">Services</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-632" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-632"><a class="anchor_scroll" href="#about">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-633" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-633"><a class="anchor_scroll" href="#partners">Partners</a></li>
```

On the inside pages of the website the links are:

```
<li id="menu-item-631" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-631"><a class="anchor_scroll" href="index.php#services">Services</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-632" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-632"><a class="anchor_scroll" href="index.php#about">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-633" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-633"><a class="anchor_scroll" href="index.php#partners">Partners</a></li>
```

This is the jquery code which implements the smooth scroll and in my opinion causes some conflicts:

```
(function($){

var jump=function(e)
{
    if (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr("href");
    }else{
        var target = location.hash;
    }
    $('html,body').animate(
        {
            scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
        },1500,'swing',function()
        {
            location.hash = target;
        });
}
$('html, body').hide()
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('a[href^=#]').bind("click", jump);
    if (location.hash){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show()
            jump()
        }, 0);
    }else{
        $('html, body').show()
    }
});
})(jQuery)
```

This code is in the separate js file which is loaded in the head of the document. As I said before, on the front page there are no errors, only on the inside pages of the website.

And also there is second question related with that js code. How can I change the desired scroll position? I need something like offset().top-150, but when I do that it slides to that position and then jumps by 150 to the previous location as it would be only the offset().top.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or url?

Comment: Can you provide code from main.js ? Because seems that other part of code produces error on pages other than main and hence execution of the scroll plugin is broken

Comment: The wordpress now is installed on the local machine. To reproduce the same issue in the fiddle is very hard because I have several plugins installed and etc. The main.js i guess is a jquery library file or something similar. Its very large. I get an error on the 48th line according the firebug.

Comment: this is the link to the errors in firebug: [image1](http://postimg.org/image/y88x068vx/) [image2](http://postimg.org/image/o3fv2butl/)

Comment: Can it be something with google maps api? This is some more details about the error: TypeError: a is null
http://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/9b/main.js
Line 48

Comment: I just now checked that after I remove the smooth scroll jquery code, the error remains. So I assume that its not related to this function. Something else is wrong with maps.